# Implementing MVVM into an existing project

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I am still fairly new to WPF, but thanks to all the resources available on the internet, I have been able to create a fairly decent (imho) presentation program. Before I began writing the program I looked at MVVM methodologies but didn't foresee my program getting as large as it did. Without going into too much detail, I have a listbox on one side that is populated with a list of properties. This is bound directly to my SQL CE database (v4.0), meaning that I need to refresh my listbox anytime changes are made to my properties. Orginally this was not an issue, but now I want to allow re-arrangement via drag and drop so I believe I will need to implement some form of observable collection to do this. Sorry if I am not making much sense, but from what I gather you can't rearrange objects directly in the database (or it isn't wise).

Basically, my issue is how do I implement an observable collection into my application, that is using my existing database for persistence? I am not worried about the work involved, so long as it is possible. Could I maybe use partial classes?

Cheers

Comment: Please post some code snippets where you are actually populating the list from database and also the bindings(if any)?

Comment: The title of this question has nothing to do with the question being asked. Binding a ListBox to an ObservableCollection has nothing to do with MVVM. You could just as easily or even more easily do it putting the logic in the code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest either looking at Caliburn Micro or Mvvm-Light.  I personally use CM.

I add to a [sample](https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/cmwpfdialogsample/src) WPF application I have on bitbucket showing how to bind a `Listbox` to a `BindableCollection` (CM's `ObservableCollection`).  There is a refresh button that populates the `BindableCollection` `MyProperties`.

There isn't much to the code as CM is doing some work for you.  I'd recommend reading through the [docs](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/documentation), they're a bit long but well worth it.

In your case you'll be populating the collection from your sqlce db.  I'm not sure if the order of the properties matter or not.  If you want to allow drag/drop to re-order and persist the order that can be done as well.

When a change is made to a property in the `ListBox` those changes will be reflected in the collection the `ListBox` is bound to.  You need to decide when you want to persist those chagnes to the DB.